# Core Data to-many relationship in code

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have three entities: Session, User and Test. A session has 0-many users and a user can perform 0-6 tests. (I say 0 but in the real application always at least 1 is required, at least 1 user for a session and at least 1 test for a user. But I say 0 to express an empty start.) All entities have their own specific data attributes too. A user has a name, A session has a name, a test has six values to be filled in by the user, and so on. But my issue is with the relationships.

1. How do I set multiple users and have them added to one session (same goes for multiple tests for one user).
2. How do I show the content in a right way? How do I show a session that has multiple users and these users having completed multiple tests?

Here's my code so far with regard to issue 1:

```
Session *session = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
session.name = @"Session 1";

User *users = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
users.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:28];
users.session = session;
//session.user = users;
[sessie addUserObject:users];
```

With regard to issue 2: I can log the session, but I can't get the user(s) logged from a session.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (Session *info in fetchedObjects) {
 NSLog(@"Name of session: %@", info.name);
 NSLog(@"Having problems with this: %@",info.user);
 //User *details = info.user;
 //NSLog(@"User: %@", details.age);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it useful (and it seems to be common practice from the code samples that I saw at SO), to use the plural form for to-many relationships, e.g. `users` for the to-many relationship from *Session* to *User*. It emphasizes the fact that the value of the relationship is a *set* and not a single object, and might make things a bit clearer.

So your model would look like this:

[image]

*Issue 1:* If you have created a `Session *session` and a `User *user`, then

```
user.session = session;
```

adds the user to the session. Calling

```
[session addUsersObject:user];
```

has the same effect. But only one of these calls is required, it automatically implies the other, if the relationships are properly defined as inverse relationships.

*Issue 2:* For a `Session *session`, `session.users` is the set of all users related to that session. It is a `NSSet` and you can iterate through that set. Similarly, `user.tests` is the set of all tests for a user.

So the following code displays all sessions with their users and tests:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *sessions = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (Session *session in sessions) {
    NSLog(@"Name of session: %@", session.name);
    for (User *user in session.users) {
        NSLog(@"   User name %@, age %@", user.name, user.age);
        for (Test *test in user.tests) {
            NSLog(@"      Test: %@", test.name);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The visual representation makes it beautiful. You got the idea! Saw it somewhere but lacked the knowledge to perform such a thing myself (i.e. to present an image). I didn't know that inverse relationship meant that you only have to declare it once, so I did it both ways. The array shows up beautifully with all sub relationships clearly presented in the log. Your effort really solves my noob issues, which can be quite hard to overcome without the right insight, as they are also easily explained, on the other hand.